# Markdown syntax to include image that works in GitHub, GitHub editor preview, and Visual Studio Code?

Tags: html, github, visual-studio-code, markdown

I am editing wiki pages on GitHub. These are markdown files and I use vs code to edit the files locally.
For example consider that I want to include `images/my-cool-image.png`

In vs code, the following syntax works well for including the image:

```
![alt text](images/my-cool-image.png)
<img src="images/my-cool-image.png">
```

It also works when viewing the page on GitHub. But it does not work in the GitHub editor's preview. It works in the GitHub editor's preview when I go one hierarchy level up via `../`.

```
![alt text](../images/my-cool-image.png)
<img src="../images/my-cool-image.png">
```

Of course this does not work in vs code on my local machine because the path is now wrong. Neither does this work when viewing the page on GitHub (not from the editor preview).

I found that the GitHub editor preview and the normal GitHub viewing both work when using the following syntax:

```
[[images/my-cool-image.png]]
```

Sadly, this syntax does not work in vs code.

Thus, so far I have:

```
                                          | GitHub editor | GitHub normal | vs code
![alt text](images/my-cool-image.png)     | no            | yes           | yes
![alt text](../images/my-cool-image.png)  | yes           | no            | no 
[[images/my-cool-image.png]]              | yes           | yes           | no
```

Is there a markdown syntax that works in GitHub editor's preview, when normally viewing the page on GitHub (not from the editor) and also in vs code?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Are you talking about the ["Preview changes" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbAfy.png) when editing a file from your browser? The form `![alt text](path/to/image)` works on all 3 for me, which is expected because that's standard Markdown syntax and is used by all 3. Is the markdown file in the same directory as the `images` folder?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about this tab. Yes, the path to the file is correct. Maybe it is a browser specific issue. I am using Firefox. I am also using no-script but it is disabled on GitHub.

Comment: I am also using Firefox, but I don't use no-script. Here are screenshots [when editing in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRr7P.png), [when viewing on Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxI6P.png), and [when using the Github Preview Changes tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMY7t.png). I suspect you have some other env-specific plugin that's causing the problem.